# Why am I getting identifier expected error in Java?

Tags: java, string

When I try to print a short name like "Koushik Gupta" to "K. Gupta" using the below method of string:

```
import java.io.*;

class Fndwrd
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   throws IOException
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String s,sn;
   System.out.println("Enter the Sentence/string");
   sn=" ";
   s=br.readLine();
   int p,l=s.length();
   p=0;
   for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
   {
       if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
       {
           sn=sn+' '+s.charAt(p);
           p=i+1;
       }
   }
   sn=sn+"."+s.substring(p);
   System.out.println("Short name\n "+sn);

 }
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You need to fix the first error first. You're missing a semicolon after your `throws IOException`.

Comment: It's `String[] args`, not `String args[]`

Comment: your main faction has no opening curly bracket { after throws IOExeption

Comment: @ShaneCoder, both actually work, it's just that the former is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing both opening and closing braces for main function.

Following is the corrected version,

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s, sn;
        System.out.println("Enter the Sentence/string");
        sn = " ";
        s = br.readLine();
        int p, l = s.length();
        p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                sn = sn + ' ' + s.charAt(p);
                p = i + 1;
            }
        }
        sn = sn + "." + s.substring(p);
        System.out.println("Short name\n " + sn);
    }
```

Comment: @koushik accept the answer if it has helped you to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the opening and closing curly braces for your main method in your program. then it will work fine. Otherwise use the following code:-

```
import java.io.*;
class Fndwrd
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s,sn;
    System.out.println("Enter the Sentence/string");
    sn=" ";
    s=br.readLine();
    int p,l=s.length();
    p=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
       if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
       {
           sn=sn+' '+s.charAt(p);
           p=i+1;
       }
    }
    sn=sn+"."+s.substring(p);
    System.out.println("Short name\n "+sn);
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you...Thanks

Comment: bt now I'm getting "missing method body, or declare abstract-public static void main pointing at- main

Comment: i think you made a mistake in the main() method definition.Could you please paste the code of your class here? so that i can fix it.

Comment: import java.io.*;
class Fndwrd
{
 public static void main(String arg[])
 throws IOException;
 
   {

 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String s,sn;
 System.out.println("Enter the Sentence/string");
 sn=" ";
 s=br.readLine();
 int p,l=s.length();
 p=0;
 for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
   {
  if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
  {
   sn=sn+' '+s.charAt(p);
   p=i+1;
  }
 }
 sn=sn+"."+s.substring(p);

 System.out.println("Short name\n "+sn);
     }
 
}

Comment: remove the semi-colon next to the throws IOException in main method definition as follows:- public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException instead of public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException;